# laravel 5: what is the purpose of service and providers directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently working laravel5 for CRM application with the help of Repository method under Provider Directory. But i'm totally look blind to understand Service Directory, and purpose of this directory.

And can anyone give me example to utilize these directories by differentiate difference.

Answer (score 8):

**Services**

Services are re-usable classes that do not belong in a controller. For example, a service which is required by more than one controller such as class for building site navigation. It is a good place to put "global" classes (global to your app), which can be injected into a controller for use across your application.

**Providers**

Providers inject services into the dependency injection system, making them easier to access across the application. Packages which are Laravel specific usually include a service provider, which ensures that the packages classes are loaded when required and available to your controllers.

Answer (score 6):

**Services** (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/structure)
The Services directory contains various "helper" services your application needs to function. For example, the Registrar service included with Laravel is responsible for validating and creating new users of your application. Other examples might be services to interact with external APIs, metrics systems, or even services that aggregate data from your own application.

**Providers**
The Providers directory purpose is basically binding the custom files with app, for example if we want to work with the repository pattern and use eloquent instead of write queries in models then we need to bind our repositories with service providers and register service provider in to config/app.php file.